# Why do these line-breaks get lost when rendered in ACF WYSIWYG field in WP Admin?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, line-breaks

I have imported text/strings from with php generated text files (utf8 with CLRF line-breaks, according to my IDE), as WP post meta data. The strings were saved as the content of a ACF WYSIWYG field. The strings contains multiple line-breaks when checking the post meta value directly inside the database. But when it gets rendered in WP Admin, every occurrence of multiple line-breaks in a row, get reduced to one line-breaks.

When re-creating the line-breaks manually, they get saved correctly. But I have to automate this somehow, as I cant edit all the data/posts manually.

I tried to convert the line-breaks with the acf/load_value filter and format_value filter but had no success so far. I also tried deactivating the wpautop function for this specific field, but nothing seems to help.

The problem is, all posts that are using this meta field cant get updated now, or the string in the database gets overwritten with the stripped line-breaks one.

What can I do to preserve the line-breaks in the string or how can I convert them to something that will not get deleted by WP?

[String inside the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A8YG.png)

[String rendered in WYSIWYG field in WP Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D89D2.png)